# Why is std::atomic_ref not implemented in terms of std::atomic

Tags: c++, atomic, c++20

The referenced implementation of std::atomic_ref from the paper [P0019r8](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0019r8.html) roughly keeps the template type as a member variable (https://github.com/ORNL/cpp-proposals-pub/blob/master/P0019/atomic_ref.hpp) and uses the GNU built-ins to implement atomic operations.

The question I have here is - why not `reinterpret_cast` to `std::atomic` and use the atomic operations instead?  Is there a portability concern or detail I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

There's no guarantee whatsoever that a `std::atomic<T>` contains nothing but a `T` and has the same size and alignment requirements as a `T`. For example, if `sizeof(T) == 3`, an implementation of `std::atomic<T>` may pad it to 4 bytes to enable the use of intrinsics. For another example, if `sizeof(T)` is too big for an intrinsic, `std::atomic<T>` might store a synchronization primitive of some sort to serialize the operation.

It follows that `reinterpret_cast` to `std::atomic` is not a viable implementation in the general case even if you ignore the general undefined behavior from the object model violations.

Answer (score 3):

Reinterpreting something to what it is not then using it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: They reinterpret_cast it to a type possibly different from the templated one in the implementation - https://github.com/ORNL/cpp-proposals-pub/blob/master/P0019/atomic_ref.hpp#L452-L453

Comment: @Curious an *implementation of C++* doesn't have to be portable. It can use UB in implementing the standard library, so long as it always chooses to generate correct programs.

Comment: @curious also, there is some alias magic tokens there.  I don't know what they do, but they probably permit aliasing to a different primitive type or something.  They are outside the C++ standard.